# Vue.js spa Authentication | can't retrieve the token from localstorage?

Tags: laravel, vue.js

My issue is that I use @websanova/vue-auth and vue-router packeges with laravel to write a spa (api authentication system). When the user logs in, they should redirect to another route (without reload) with a token set in the localsorage. In my `resources/bootstrap.js` file when I retrieve the token from localstorage, it returns "null" even though I checked the token's value in the browser's inspector.

Here is my bootstrap.js:

```
const token = localStorage.getItem('token')
 window.Echo = new Echo({
     broadcaster: 'pusher',
     key: 'ec356bcd******',
     cluster: 'ap2',
     encrypted: true,
     host: 'http://1227.0.0.1:8000',
     authEndpoint: 'api/broadcasting/auth',
     auth: {
        headers: {
          Authorization: 'Bearer ' + token
        },
      },
 });
```

So

```
Authorization: 'Bearer ' + token
```

returns :

```
Authorization: 'Bearer null'
```

but if I refresh the page everything works great but as my application is spa the user should not refresh the page

Comment: Because you are setting the token in localStorage *after* the bootstrap.js is loaded and this statement has run: `const token = localStorage.getItem('token');`, which means when it ran for the first time it was null, because there was no token in localStorage at that point of time. You just have to make sure you are accessing the token after it has been set.

Comment: well, any idea of how can i access the token after it is set ?

Comment: Move the `window.Echo = new Echo()` statement after `localStorage.setItem(token)`?